# Lawn sprinkler stays on

Tags: sprinkler-system

My lawn sprinkler system has 4 zones and I noticed that one zone is staying on all the time. Even if I set the timer controller to off position, that valve stays on. If I unplug the controller, the valve shuts off. I tried doing a reset on the controller and it made no difference. Do I need to replace the controller?

Comment: is it possible to swap the wires of the valves to another channel? Try and see if the faulty valve goes off by pluggin it into that zone.. if it does. then yes.. something is wrong with the controller. other wise the valve or cables are faulty

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the controller is working correctly again after leaving it unplugged for a day. It is possible it went haywire after getting wet from one of the adjacent sprinklers that was misadjusted. I adjusted the sprinkler and put a plastic bag over the controller until I can replace it with a proper outdoor controller model (as the previous owner used an indoor model with no cover.)